# Inline Edit on Child - Update Parent

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a parent component that passes a list of records to a child.

```
<c-gs-list account-id={accountId} filteredgroupstructures={filteredgroupstructures} onclose = {refreshHandler}></c-gs-list>
```

From the child, I want to be able to edit in the datatable (inline editing).  I have this working, however, the parent is not refreshing.  I have looked at getREcordNotifyChange but thats now working for me.

Here is my lightning-datatable in the child:

```
<lightning-datatable
                                id="pdftable"
                                data={filteredgroupstructures}
                                columns={columns}
                                column-widths-mode={auto}
                                key-field="Id"
                                sorted-by={sortBy}
                                sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                                onsort={handleSortdata}
                                onrowaction={handleRowActions}
                                draft-values={draftValues}
                                onsave={handleSave}>
                        </lightning-datatable>
```

Here is my handleSave method on child:

```
handleSave(event) {
  const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
    // Prepare the record IDs for getRecordNotifyChange()
  const notifyChangeIds = updatedFields.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });

  try {
    // Pass edited fields to the updateContacts Apex controller
    const result = updateGs({data: updatedFields});
    getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeIds);

      // Clear all draft values in the datatable when done
    this.draftValues = [];
      //reset the columns to remove the highlighting of those that were updated
    this.columns = [...this.columns]; 
    
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
          title: 'Success',
          message: 'Group Structures updated',
          variant: 'success'
      })
  );
```

} catch(error) {
this.dispatchEvent(
new ShowToastEvent({
title: 'Error updating or refreshing records',
message: error.body.message,
variant: 'error'
})
);
};

```
  //call closeHandler to pass data back to parent component
  this.closeHandlerParent()

}
```

And finally, here is the refreshHandler in the parent component.

```
//triggered from grandchild or child to refresh data form changes on child and grandchild components
     refreshHandler(event){
      console.log('Im in the refreshHandler on gsWizard');
            refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
            refreshApex(this.getgroupstructurelist);
          
          }
```

Updated - here is the start of the wire that includes the refreshapex.. there is a lot of code in the wire.. let me know if you need the entire wire.

```
 @wire(getgroupstructures, {accountId:'$accountId'})
groupstructures(result) {
  console.log('im in the wire ' );
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

      //variables to set data and filter fields
      var GroupNumbersList = [];
      var GroupNumbersListDeduped = [];
      var SectionsList = [];
      var SectionsListDeduped = [];
      var PackagesList = [];
      var PackagesListDeduped = [];
      var ProductsList = [];
      var ProductsListDeduped = [];

    //if we have data returned
  if (result.data && result.data.length) {
              //assign the data to the data variable - used as the source for the main datatable
            this.data = result.data;
            

              //set the groupstructurelist with all group structures returned for account - this variable ALWAyS
              // holds all of the returned group structures, even when the data variable is fitlered
            this.groupstructurelist = result.data;
              //also set the filteredgroupstructures variable which is used as a go-between when fitlering the data variable
            this.filteredgroupstructures = result.data;
              //since we have data, update error to undefined
            this.error = undefined;
              //set the numberrecords field w hich displays on the page
            this.numberrecords= this.data.length;
              //set the account name field from first gs in list
           ///// this.accountName =this.data[0].Account__r.Name;

              //needed when we need to refresh the table based on changes in child and grandchild components
            this.refreshTable = result;
```

...............
...............

The refreshHandler is getting called but the wire does not get called to refresh the records.  I have successfully added edit pages and new record pages but I'm unsure of how to refresh the list on the primary component after updating from the child using inline editing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  thanks!

Comment: Can you post your @wire for refreshTable and getgroupstructurelist?

Comment: Thanks for responding CyberJus... I updated my post to include the start of the wire.  There is a lot of code in wire because I have filters that I set up.  Also, the wire never gets called from the parents method.  thanks again!

Comment: Your refreshApex is not going to execute the logic after the wire returns again. If you need to post process the data, call then() after the refresh apex. Move your logic into a combined method and call from the wire and your refresh.

Comment: Thanks again.  Do you know why this same functionality works on my new record and edit records but not when I edit on the data table inline?  I’m using the same method on the parent and the refresh works on the new and edit sub components.  Thank you!!

Comment: I would have to see what you are doing there. The refresh works and binds to the same record, it is just what you are doing afterwards in your method that might matter.

Comment: I just have one more question.  I have a console.log at the top of my wire.  That console.log does not fire at all when I update in my inline editing.  So I'm unsure how moving the logic to a separate method will help if the data form the wire is not getting refreshed now.  thanks!

Comment: You would move the process logic to another method and then call that method from both the @wire and the then() of your refreshApex. Then it happens from both places without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue.  This post had the answer I needed:  [Refresh specific LDS cache entry in lightning web component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324411/refresh-specific-lds-cache-entry-in-lightning-web-component)  Using getRecordNotifyChange